# Qgis web client / Openlayers

Tags: web, client, openlayers, qgis

I need your help. I use the Qgis web client and I want to use codes like this:

```
map.events.register("click", map , function(e){
var opx = map.getLayerPxFromViewPortPx(e.xy) ;  
...  
...
```

I tried to insert this code in *nearly* every *js-file* in the *webclient-folder* (*qgis-web-client* / *site* / js), but with no success.

Can anybody say me HOW and in WHAT js-file(and in what section of the file) I have to insert codes like this? For exampe: I like to open a popup by clicking on a map-item.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use latest GIT version of Qgis Web Client, you could use the new file Customizations.js and write it into the function `customAfterMapInit`.